# APACHE IGNITE : Join query on tables with different caches

Tags: sql, ignite

Apache Ignite : I have two caches which have table person in one cache and city table in another cache and i am trying to get name from person who's id is equal with id which is in city table so i want to make join query who will work for that please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query for your requirement:-

```
List<List<?>> qry = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from table1 as t1, table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.foreignId")).getAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `SELECT * FROM "Cache1".table1 t1 JOIN "Cache2".table2 t2 ON t2.foreignId = t1.id`?

Comment: But we fire a query using cache name eg- igncachDesignation.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * from designation")).getAll();  So as i have different caches it shows me error of schema not found.

Comment: List<List<?>> join = igncachName.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT p.id,p.name from \"igncachName\".person p join \"igncachcity\".city c on p.id = c.id")).getAll();

Comment: Schema is case sensitive, are you sure you have correct schema? I ask since you have different case in `igncachName` and `igncachcity`.

Comment: no,i used name as it is,but now the issue is solved,thanks for your ans